# Stopping file choosing dialog from opening jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to stop a file selection dialog from opening if a user is not logged in, i.e. getUIDFromCookie() returns 0.  Here is my code.

```
            file.on('focus', function(event){
                if (getUIDfromCookie() == 0 ){  // not logged in
                  console.log('uid: .' +getUIDfromCookie() + '.');
                  event.preventDefault();
                  event.stopPropagation();
                  return false;
             }
```

Problem:  The file dialog opens even though I do see uid: .0. in the log.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you can not change behavior of `file inputs` through javascript API, you can try `disabled` attribute (for anonymous users)

Example Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (getUIDfromCookie() == 0 ){  // not logged in
        $("#file-input-id").prop("disabled", "disabled");
    }
});
</script>
```